# Debian xfce changing to virtual console on alt + f4

Tags: debian, xfce

Recently I installed debian 10 with xfce as desktop environment.
The problem that I'm facing is when pressing alt + f4 to close an application, it's changing to virtual console 4 (as if I was pressing ctrl + alt + f4).

I would like to know how I could change it to only change to the virtual console if ctrl + alt + f1, f2, etc is being pressed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings Manager → Window Manager → Keyboard (tab) and look for the action called Close window.

There select the action, click the Edit button and choose a different keybinding combination for this action.